# Custom validator is not working

Tags: javascript

Custom validator in my form is not working please check the javascript and code below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkalphabets(sender, args) {
        var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/;
        var regexp1 = new RegExp("(www|http|https|WWW|HTTP|HTTPS)");
        var sUser = <%= CreateFirstNameTextBox.ClientID %>.value;
        if ((!pattern.test(args.value))|| (regexp1.test(args.value))) 
        {
            return false;
        }
            return true;
    }

</script>


<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="CreateFirstNameTextBox" placeholder="First Name"
        MaxLength="50"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Only Alphabets allowed! & http, www, https are not allowed"
        ClientValidationFunction="checkalphabets" ForeColor="red" ControlToValidate="CreateFirstNameTextBox"
        ValidationGroup="create" />


    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" ValidationGroup="create" />
</div>
</form>
```

i have to allow only alphabets to textbox and should not allow www, http, https

Comment: can you show the rendered code rather then the template. might make it easier knowing the actual code being run

Comment: do you see any errors in console?

Comment: Its not working @Grundy

Comment: @DurairajKj - _not working_ is too broad. How it not working: do nothing? any errors? or what?

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
        function checkalphabets(sender, args) {
            var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/;
            var regexp1 = new RegExp("(www|http|https|WWW|HTTP|HTTPS)");
            var sUser = <%= CreateFirstNameTextBox.ClientID %>.value;
            if ((!pattern.test(sUser))|| (regexp1.test(sUser))) 
            {
                return false;
            }
                return true;
        }
        
    </script>`

Comment: i have to allow only the alphabets and i should not allow http, https, www in the same text box

Comment: but in your OP you check only one condition

Answer (score 0):

You need see in MSDN about [ClientValidationFunction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.clientvalidationfunction(v=vs.110).aspx) in example you can see that in validation function you need setup `IsValid` property for arguments, so you need change your code like

```
function checkalphabets(sender, args) {
    var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/;
    var regexp1 = new RegExp("(www|http|https|WWW|HTTP|HTTPS)");
    var sUser = args.Value; //<%= CreateFirstNameTextBox.ClientID %>.value;

    args.IsValid = pattern.test(sUser);
}
```

also instead `<%= CreateFirstNameTextBox.ClientID %>.value` better use `args.Value`

**Update** for use both condition

```
function checkalphabets(sender, args) {
    var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/;
    var regexp1 = new RegExp("(www|http|https|WWW|HTTP|HTTPS)");
    var sUser = args.Value; //<%= CreateFirstNameTextBox.ClientID %>.value;

    args.IsValid = pattern.test(sUser) && !regexp1.test(sUser);
}
```